# Suggestions on matlab/python conversion

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to translate the matlab code below to a python code. The code calculates numerical the para-state of a deuterium molecule and then plots the result. When I try to translate it to python, it seems that I get stuck in a nested for-loop which calculates a sum. I have been searching on the internet the past days yet without success.

Because it's a physics code I will mention some aspect from the code. So first we calculate the partition function (Z). After that there is a calculation of the energy which is a partial derivative of ln(Z) to beta. From this we can calculate the specific heat (approximately) as the derivative of energy to temperature.

So the matlab code looks like this:

```
epsilon = 0.0038*1.60217662*10^-19;
k = 1.38*10^-23;
T = 1:.1:2000;
beta = 1./(k*T);

%partitionfunction
clear Z Zodd;
for i = 1:length(T)  
    clear p;    
    for s = 1:2:31;
        a = 2*s+1;
        b = s^2+s;
        p(s) = 3*a*exp(-b*epsilon*beta(i));
    end
    Zodd(i) = sum(p);
end

%energy
ln_Zodd = log(Zodd); 

for i = 1 : (length(T)-1)
    Epara(i) = -(ln_Zodd(i+1)-ln_Zodd(i))/(beta(i+1)-beta(i));
end

%heat capacity
for i = 1 : (length(T)-2)
    Cpara(i) = (Epara(i+1)-Epara(i))/(T(i+1)-T(i));
end   

%plot
x = k*T/epsilon;
plot(x(1:6000),Cpara(1:6000)/k, 'r');
axis([0 7 0 1.5]);
ylabel('C_v/k');
xlabel('kT/eps');
```

The corresponding python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

epsilon=0.0038*1.60217662*10**-19
k = 1.38*10**-23
T = np.arange(1,2000,0.1)
beta = 1/(k*T)

#partitionfunction
for i in np.arange(1,len(T)): 
    for s in np.arange(1,31,2):
    p[s] = 3*(2*s+1)*math.exp(-(s**2+s)*epsilon*beta(i))
    Zodd[i] = sum(p)

#energy
ln_Zodd = math.log(Zodd)

for i in np.arange(1,(len(T) - 1)):
    Epara[i]=- (ln_Zodd(i + 1) - ln_Zodd(i)) / (beta(i + 1) - beta(i))

#heat capacity
for i in np.arange(1,(len(T) - 2)):
    Cpara[i]=(Epara(i + 1) - Epara(i)) / (T(i + 1) - T(i))

#plot
x = k*T/epsilon
plt.plot(x(np.arange(1,6000)),Cpara(np.arange(1,6000)) / k,'r')
plt.axis([0, 7, 0, 1.5]) 
plt.ylabel('C_v/k')
plt.xlabel('kT/eps')   
plt.show()
```

This should be the easiest way to calculate (approximate) this problem because the analytic expression is way more involved. I'm new to python so any suggestions or corrections are appreciated.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  This kind of question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @rayryeng that this question is off-topic. However, as I'm interested in matlab, python, *and* theoretical physics, I took the time to look through your code.

There are multiple syntactical problems with it, and multiple semantical ones as well. Arrays should always be accessed by `[]` in python, often you try to use `()`. And the natural indexing of arrays starts from 0, unlike matlab.

Here's a syntactically and semantically corrected version of your original code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import math  #use np.* if you have it already imported

epsilon=0.0038*1.60217662*10**-19
k = 1.38*10**-23
T = np.arange(1,2000,0.1)
beta = 1.0/(k*T) #changed to 1.0 for safe measure; redundant

#partitionfunction
svec=np.arange(1,31,2)
p=np.zeros(max(svec)) #added pre-allocation
Zodd=np.zeros(len(T)) #added pre-allocation
for i in np.arange(len(T)): #changed to index Zodd from 0
    for s in svec:  #changed to avoid magic numbers
        p[s-1] = 3*(2*s+1)*np.exp(-(s**2+s)*epsilon*beta[i])   #changed to index p from 0; changed beta(i) to beta[i]; changed to np.exp
    Zodd[i] = sum(p)

#energy
ln_Zodd = np.log(Zodd)  #changed to np.log

Epara=np.zeros(len(T)-2)  #added pre-allocation
for i in np.arange(len(T) - 2): #changed to index Epara from 0
    Epara[i]=- (ln_Zodd[i + 1] - ln_Zodd[i]) / (beta[i + 1] - beta[i])   #changed bunch of () to []

#heat capacity
Cpara=np.zeros(len(T)-3)  #added pre-allocation
for i in np.arange(len(T) - 3): #changed to index Cpara from 0
    Cpara[i]=(Epara[i + 1] - Epara[i]) / (T[i + 1] - T[i])

#plot
x = k*T/epsilon
plt.plot(x[:6000],Cpara[:6000] / k,'r')  #fixed and simplified array indices
plt.axis([0, 7, 0, 1.5])
plt.ylabel('C_v/k')
plt.xlabel('kT/eps')
plt.show()
```

Take the time to look through the comments I made, they are there to instruct you. If something is not clear, please ask for clarification:)

However, this code is far from efficient. Especially your double loop takes a long time to run (which might explain why you think it hung). So I also made it very `numpy`-based.

Here's the result:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as consts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epsilon=0.0038*consts.eV  #changed eV
k = consts.k  #changed
T = np.arange(1,2000,0.1)
beta = 1.0/(k*T) #changed to 1.0 for safe measure; redundant

#partitionfunction
s=np.arange(1,31,2)[:,None]
Zodd = (3*(2*s+1)*np.exp(-(s**2+s)*epsilon*beta)).sum(axis=0)

#energy
ln_Zodd = np.log(Zodd)  #changed to np.log
#Epara = - (ln_Zodd[1:]-ln_Zodd[:-1])/(beta[1:]-beta[:-1])  #manual version
Epara = - np.diff(ln_Zodd)/np.diff(beta)

#heat capacity
Cpara=np.diff(Epara)/np.diff(T)[:-1]

#plot
x = k*T/epsilon
plt.plot(x[:len(Cpara)],Cpara / k,'r')  #fixed and simplified array indices
plt.axis([0, 7, 0, 1.5])
plt.ylabel('C_v/k')
plt.xlabel('kT/eps')
plt.show()
```

Again, please review the changes made. I made use of the `scipy.constants` module to import physical constants to high precision. I also made use of array broadcasting, which allowed me to turn your double loop into a sum of a matrix along one of its dimensions (just like how you should have done it in matlab; your original matlab code is also far from efficient).

Here's the common result:

[image: heat capacity vs T]

You can see that it seems right: at high temperature you get the Dulong--Petit behaviour, and at `T->0` we get the zero limit in accordance with the third law of thermodynamics. The heat capacity decays exponentially, but this should make sense since you have a finite energy gap.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I'm sorry for making mistakes and posting it wrong, but I'm still learning. The first correction really makes sense, never thought to use a pre-allocation. Initially I used [] in my whole loop, but as I had still issues I discarded that after a while.

The second one is still a bit unclear. Could you maybe explain what the [:,None] and the [:-1] do, respectively in the partitionfunction and the heat capacity?

Comment: Thanks for moving your answer to a comment:) The more straightforward thing is `[:-1]`: in python, arrays are indexed from 0, and when you say `arr[0:n]`, then index `n` is actually not used, the index list ends at `n-1`. negative indices are counted from the back of the array, so `arr[-1]` is matlab's `arr(end)`, and `arr[:-1]` in python is equivalent to `arr(1:end-1)` in matlab (in python, missing number in a `from:to` indexing are implicitly understood as the minimal/maximal corresponding value, so `arr[1:]` is equivalent to matlab's `arr(2:end)`).

Comment: And `[:,None]` is a tricky way of turning your 1d array into a column vector. It is equivalent to the numpy command `[:,np.newaxis]`, and its effect will be to introduce a singleton dimension in the array. So if your array was `arr=np.array([1,3,4])`, which is essentially a row vector, it has shape `(3,)`, so it isn't 2-dimensional. Using `arr[None,:]` will turn it into a 2d array of shape `(1,3)` (an explicit row vector), and `arr[:,None]` will turn it into a 2d array of shape `(3,1)` (a column vector). While 1d arrays and 2d row vectors are compatible, for a column vector you need `[:,None]`

Comment: Okay that clarifies al lot, you have learnt me some interesting new techniques